# How to get Telegram channel Profile Photo with TelegramBotClient

Tags: telegram

I'm using C# TelegramBotClient library.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var bot = new TelegramBotClient("apiKey");
var chat = await bot.GetChatAsync("@channelName");
```

[image]

What should I do with BigFileId to get image?

Answer (score 0):

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var bot = new TelegramBotClient("apiKey");
        var chat = await bot.GetChatAsync("@channelName")
        Telegram.Bot.Types.File p = await bot.GetFileAsync(chat.Photo.BigFileId);
        string filePath = p.FilePath;

        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var file = bot.GetInfoAndDownloadFileAsync(p.FileId, outputStream).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var array = outputStream.ToArray();
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(array))
            {
                var image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                image.Save("C:\\test\\image.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
```